# ActiveRecord query ModelName.where("column_A_value = ?", column_B_value)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a PostgreSQL table that represents a tree structure where text values for any given sub-category are NOT unique. For instance, "books > automobiles" does not have the same category_id as "advertising > automobiles." Each category_id IS unique, and applies to only one hierarchy, but the sub-categories can be as many as 5 layers deep, so there are thousands of category_ids, whose parent_ids each represent only the immediate parent.

The top-level categories have a parent_id equal to the category_id, but I haven't found the correct syntax to search for them, using either straight SQL or ActiveRecord. I thought I could use the following:

```
Category.where("category_id = ?", parent_id)
```

but that doesn't work--  I get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `parent_id' for main:Object
```

I've tried using

```
 Category.where("category_id = ?", "parent_id")
```

but both values are integers, and I get a type mismatch error.

Is there a way to return an array of records where the values of two columns within the same record are equal?

Comment: Are you looking to do something like this? `SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = parent_id;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Category.where('category_id = parent_id')
```